# attempt to index a nil value items(help!)

Tags: lua, lua-table, fivem

so im gettin this error so i know theres something i probably gotta fix here but i have no idea how .thanks

> SCRIPT ERROR: @gcphone/server/server.lua:205: attempt to index a nil value (local 'items')

CODE FROM LINE 205

```
ESX.RegisterServerCallback('crew-phone:phone-check', function(source, cb)
    local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(source)
    if not xPlayer then return; end
    for k, v in pairs(Config.Phones) do
        local items = xPlayer.getInventoryItem(v)
        if items.count > 0 then
            cb(v)
            return
        end
    end
    cb(nil)
end)

ESX.RegisterServerCallback('crew-phone:item-check', function(source, cb, data)
    local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(source)
    if not xPlayer then return; end
    local items = xPlayer.getInventoryItem(data)
    cb(items.count)
end)
```

Comment: `getInventoryItem()` returned `nil`

Answer (score 0):

This error tells you that items is a nil value and Lua complains about it because you try to index it as in `items.count`. That doesn't make sense if `items` is `nil`
It's like referring to a book page of a non-existant book.

`local items` is `nil` because `xPlayer.getInventoryItem(data)` returned `nil`

Check wether the local script provides a string for `data` when triggering the server event and if xPlayer actually has an item like that.

Also check your `RegisterServerCallback`. The function you define there is the callback. Why is there another callback in that function argument? I think you're confusing things and probably should refer to the manual again.

https://esx-framework.github.io/es_extended/server/functions/registerservercallback/